# extracting number with decimal points from text extracted from pdf files

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I need to extract only numbers with a decimal point from the following string. I used **re** module but faced a problem with a number of commas(there can be no commas or more than 1). Another problem is decimal numbers followed by words (i.e. **1,513,971.63**Savings ). As I extracted the string from PDF files so I can't change the format.

#### sample string:

```
Date: 01-Mar-2022BETKA Br (0225)LIABILITIESCUSTOMER DEPOSITS 19,858,700.86Current Deposit12102010010165 350,745,799.38Saving Deposits12102010050170 174,381.98SB Bidhaba Bhata12102010060171 1,125,990.66SB Bayaska Bhata12102010070172 131,647.15SB Pratibandhy
```

#### output:

```
19,858,700.86
350,745,799.38
174,381.98
1,125,990.66
131,647.15
```

Anyone help?

Comment: Please use the `{}` buttons to preserve code or flat files and whitespace. Are the asterisks in your file literal or just used for highlighting your data points?

Comment: If the number string can contain commas or not contain commas then how do you know, as a human, that you don't want `12102010010165` but you DO you want `350,745,799.38`?  Do they always have a decimal in them? If not is there any other way that you, as a human, are able to determine which is a good number and which is a bad number? Perhaps the pattern is ALWAYS <long number><space><the number you want>?

Comment: Yes,  they always have a decimal in them. It actually means currency, which I need to work with. Other numbers are not necessary for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you missed the **174,381.98**. If so, use `(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)+)` pattern to get the expected result.

```
import re

string = """Date: 01-Mar-2022BETKA Br (0225)LIABILITIESCUSTOMER DEPOSITS 19,858,700.86Current Deposit12102010010165 350,745,799.38Saving Deposits12102010050170 174,381.98SB Bidhaba Bhata12102010060171 1,125,990.66SB Bayaska Bhata12102010070172 131,647.15SB Pratibandhy"""

print(*re.findall(r"(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)+)", string), sep="\n")
```